# Launching python from idle, or better IDE options

Tags: python, macos, compilation, python-idle

I have been using IDLE to program in python for the time being, and it is starting to get tedious to launch it from terminal.  I have looked online to try to find a solution for this but haven't found out how to launch it in a typical Mac like way from spotlight (I have already tried putting it into the applications folder).

I am also open to any other suggestions for any better IDE's that work the same way as IDLE, with its own built in compiler.

Comment: try either PyCharm or VS code.

Comment: If you install tkinter and IDLE with Python on Windows with the python.org installer, the latter creates an IDLE entry in the start menu.  I pin the icon on the taskbar.  One click and it opens.  I am guessing that you are using linux or some other *nix.  Use whatever quick launch option your system has.  There is nothing special about IDLE in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Try Visual Studio Code, it comes with everything you need for Python development, including a feature to launch and test your program from the application.

It's free and open source, you can pick it up [here](https://code.visualstudio.com) :)

Comment: I have tried to use this, as I really enjoy using it for other languages, but I can't seem to have it connect with python3 that I installed with pip3.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Ensure you have the "Python" extension installed from the Visual Studio marketplace. It will not work without this. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Pycharm IDE. It is a JetBrain Product
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/